# How to handle error while running react application with the following error message?

Tags: reactjs, npm

[image: Error text]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you use node-sass package?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing at the error, I guess you forgot to add the specific loader in webpack to make the JS compiler understand your converted css.

One more suggestion is to add ErrorBoundaries to your components to understand whether this error is at component level or at bootstrap time.